# Оператор "или" в фильтре angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли в ангуляре в стандартном фильтре задать условие "или"?
Что-то типа такого: `tour in tours | filter : **{country: tourType}||{type: tourType}** : true"`

В качестве "и" можно поставить 2 фильтра подряд `({country: tourType} | filter : {type: tourType})`, а есть ли какой-то вариант для "или"?

Понятно, что можно просто создать свой фильтр, но меня интересует именно решение "из коробки" есть, или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Такого функционала увы нет. Хотя не понятно в чем проблема написать новый фильтр. Рост приложения без увеличения его кода - это не возможно )

Если фильтр простой, то можно создать его обычной функцией в контроллере:

**Angular**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in products | filter:fruitOrVeg">{{item.name}}</li>
```

**JS:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.products = [
        {name:"Apple",type:"fruit"},
        {name:"Grape",type:"fruit"},
        {name:"Orage",type:"fruit"},
        {name:"Carrot",type:"vegetable"},
        {name:"Milk",type:"dairy"}
    ];

    $scope.fruitOrVeg = function(product){
        // Любые условия, и любое их количество
        return product.type == 'fruit' || product.type == 'vegetable';
        // return (product.type == 'dairy' 
        //    || product.type == 'vegetable') 
        //    && product.name == 'Milk';
    };
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был признателен вам за пример фильтра.

Comment: Спасибо. Собственно я сразу сделал собственный фильтр, просто не очень хочется лепить велосипеды вместо существующего функционала. Но если такого функционала не, тогда ладно.